# Stopping a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating a thread in my Python app with `thread.start_new_thread`.

How do I stop it if it hasn't finished in three seconds time?

Comment: You might be interested in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196999/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-a-function-in-python-cross-platform) on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you are downloading data, you can set a socket timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this (e.g. the thread calls code that may hang forever) then consider rewriting your code to spawn a process with the multiprocessing module.  You can then kill the process with the Process.terminate() method.  You will need 2.6 or later for this, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly. Anyway aborting a thread is not good practice - rather think about using synchronization mechanisms that let you abort the thread in a "soft" way.

But [daemonic threads](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) will automatically be aborted if no non-daemonic threads remain (e.g. if the only main thread ends). Maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Threads can't be killed from outside. The only thing you can do is add a way to ask the thread to exit. Obviously you won't be able to do this if the thread is blocked in some systemcall.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python), you might be able to raise an exception through `ctypes.pythonapi`, but not while it's waiting on a system call.