# How to skip an iteration in Python for-loop when a particular statement is taking more time to execute?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a read_sql call inside a for loop, which takes a lot of time to return a value sometimes.
Is it possible to skip the loop when it is taking more than 5 mins to execute read_sql?

```py
for i in range(columns):
    value=pd.read_sql() # skip this statement when it takes more than 5 mins to return
    # other operation
```

Comment: you can use `Threading` with `timeout` to timeout code exeuction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196999/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-a-function-in-python this will help.