# Stop processing value in loop if time reaches more than a second?

Tags: python, time

Is there any module that exists that will stop the execution of a specific value in a loop if the time taken to compute reaches more than a specific amount of seconds?

For example, in the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(socket.gethostbyname(entry[i]))
```

If it takes longer than 1 second to compute socket.gethostbyname(entry[i]), I want it to skip and go to the next one.

Thanks!

Comment: At a guess (there may be some nicer functionality, possibly in an external package), you'd need to create a thread, put the gethostbyname functionality in that thread, keep a timer in another thread, and when the timer surpasses a set time (one second) and that thread ends, kill the first thread as well.

Comment: Related question (but not exactly a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196999/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-a-function-in-python .

Comment: I think you can call this before your loop https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout